# How can i have it so it add exp every time a message is sent on a Discord bot made in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

the code (shown below) is supposed to add exp points to a user on discord. The problem is that it adds the exp 1 time but never add again. the exp value of that user stays at 10.

```
import discord
import json
import os
from discord.ext import commands

token = ""
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\aryaa\Desktop\testing')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Is Ready')
    print('------')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    await update_data(users, member)
    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 10)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await client.send(channel, '{} has leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end

client.run(token)
```

here's the .json file that holds the user information. As you can see it shows 10 expr. I had sent about 15 messages but this value never shifts so I have no clue what the reason behind this not updating is.

```
{"431524570131070988": {"experience": 10, "level": 1}}
```

Comment: Is everything else working fine? Does the bot react to messages etc.
Also which version of discord.py are you running?

Comment: this code is a small exert from the main bot code that I am testing in another file. The code for the main bot for other interactions works fine and uses the same structure. also, my discord.py version is 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem. So basically your `users` dictionary has integers as keys. The problem is **JSON doesnt support integer keys** so when you use `json.dump` all of your integer keys get converted into strings. Now obviously an integer key is not the same as a string key so you are always overwriting the data of your user as if they are a new user.

This is solved by creating a new function, which, after `json.load`, makes all keys to integers again:

```py
def int_keys(users):
    new_users = {}
    for key, value in users.items():
        new_users[int(key)] = value
    return new_users

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message)
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    users = int_keys(users)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 10)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Also, I would really reccomend using the discord.py rewrite if you can. It makes a lot of stuff simpler.

Edit: Also add it to the member_join script:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    users = int_keys(users)
    await update_data(users, member)
    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Comment: That fixed the major errors but now throughout my code, I get errors stating      TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression.                                            do I need to import aysyncio?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with my added code, as I never added an await expression anywhere. I've also never gotten this error when I tested my addition to your script. What does the traceback look like? On which line is the error?

Comment: @Ary_2121 I'm happy to help :) It's quite stupid that json.dump just turns integers into strings without raising an Error.

Comment: @Ary_2121 is everything alright now? Is the issue fixed? Cause you never actually closed the thread.